# Dashcode Lists in Firefox

Tags: javascript, list, dashcode

I have a list in dashcode where I update a parameter for the datasource and tell the list to reload. The code is fully functional when view from Safari but the reload command does not appear to work when the same page is viewed in Firefox. The code I am using to update my data source is:

```
dataSource.setValueForKeyPath("keyboard/build/", "parameters.directory");
var list= document.getElementById('list');                      
list.object.reloadData();
```

Is there a different command I need to send for firefox to reload the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that firefox does not work well with globally declared variables, I got rid of the variables in my script and the page loaded no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Dashboad widgets use special, nonstandard Javascript APIs that aren't availible in most Javascript environments.  Does Firefox present any errors in its Javascript console (get [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) if you don't have it already).  Try testing the same issue in Chrome to see if this is a Webkit vs Gecko issue or a Apple vs Everyone Else issue.

Comment: From the firebug console I see the data being retried initially when the page is uploaded but the call for the reloaded data never seems to be processed. No other errors appear. Any ideas?